# Use JavaScript to convert a date string with timezone to a date object in local time

Tags: javascript, datetime, timezone

The format of my date string looks like this: `yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ss-0Z00`

**Example 1**: `2010-03-05T07:03:51-0800`

**Example 2**: `2010-07-01T20:23:00-0700`

I need to create a date object using these date strings. `new Date()` does not work on this string.
Please help me convert these date strings into a date objects with the local timezone.

Thank you!

Edit: I am using this in Pentaho Data Integration 4.3.0.

Comment: it is a [rfc 3339](http://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc3339#section-5.8) format a profile of ISO 8601. `new Date("2010-07-01T20:23:00-0700")` works for me in Firefox/Chrome.

Comment: I am using it in Pentaho Data Integration.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

You can use a library such as [Moment.js](http://momentjs.com) to do this.

See the String + Format parsing.

http://momentjs.com/docs/#/parsing/string-format/

The following *should* parse your date you provided, but you may need to modify it for your needs.

```
var oldDate = "2010-03-05T07:03:51-0800";

var dateObj = moment(oldDate, "YYY-MM-DDTHH:mm:ssZ").toDate();
```

Alternatively, see Moment's String parser, which looks like it is in the format you provided, with the exception of a space between the seconds of the time and the time zone.

http://momentjs.com/docs/#/parsing/string/

### Alternative

A second way of doing this is Date.js, another library that seems to parse the format just fine. http://www.datejs.com

Comment: It's not working for me. It takes my current timezone only in Date object. Please help

Comment: This shouldn't be the correct answer, if the question says "with timezone". Moment doesn't consider the timezone offset, instead uses the system's timezone. Why would you use a library for something that can also be done by parsing date using native JS.

Answer (score 40):

Take my timezone as an example (AEST):

```
function parseDate(str_date) {
  return new Date(Date.parse(str_date));
}


var str_date = "2015-05-01T22:00:00+10:00"; //AEST time
var locale_date = parseDate(str_date);
```

locale_date: Fri May 01 2015 22:00:00 GMT+1000 (AEST)

```
var str_date = "2015-05-01T22:00:00+00:00" //UTC time
var locale_date = parseDate(str_date);
```

locale_date: Sat May 02 2015 08:00:00 GMT+1000 (AEST)

Comment: This should be the correct answer, thanks for the help.

Comment: It is not working in Safari Mac. new Date(Date.parse("2017-12-13GMT+0530"))

Answer (score 14):

Date String:

`var strDate = "2010-07-01T20:23:00-0700";`

To local time representation in native JS Date object:

`var ltzDate = (new Date(strDate)).toLocaleString();`

Comment: Does not work for me. (I am using this in Pentaho Data Integration)

Comment: Sorry about that. I tested this in Chrome (Developer Tools console), and it worked fine for me. Since this is standard ECMAScript (JavaScript), I assumed it would work everywhere.

Comment: It's not work in safari. you should use this format  "2010-07-01T20:23:00-07:00" with :