# What timestamp type is this? Can't convert to date at all in JS

Tags: javascript, timestamp

`2014-11-12T8:30:00-000Z` is the timestamp I can't figure out. I tried many different sites to convert and different approaches in JavaScript but I can't get the `Date()` method to like it!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Use JavaScript to convert a date string with timezone to a date object in local time](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11770367/use-javascript-to-convert-a-date-string-with-timezone-to-a-date-object-in-local)

Comment: and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1728404/date-format-yyyy-mm-ddthhmmssz