# Convert datetime zone string to datetime javascript

Tags: javascript, mysql, datetime, pentaho, pdi

I try to convert the format: 2017-03-07T17:26:15-03:00 to a format like

yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm:ss for i can use DateTime in MySQL DataBase. I receveid those values from a XML file.

I find a lot of options here, but not working, i'm using PDI from Pentaho to convert the XML and save in a Database.

[Use JavaScript to convert a date string with timezone to a date object in local time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11770367/use-javascript-to-convert-a-date-string-with-timezone-to-a-date-object-in-local)

Thanks so much.

Comment: use moment.js?.

Comment: is this your javascript datetime?

Comment: have you tried Select Values Step?
In select values in meta-data tab we have option of changing the format.

Answer (score 0):

You can extract individual date parts and combine them to get the desired string. Something like this:

```js
var d = new Date('2017-03-07T17:26:00-03:00');
var result = d.getFullYear()+
    '/'+('0' + (d.getMonth()+1)).slice(-2)+
    '/'+('0' + d.getDate()).slice(-2)+
    ' '+('0' + d.getHours()).slice(-2)+
    ':'+('0' + d.getMinutes()).slice(-2)+
    ':'+('0' + d.getSeconds()).slice(-2);
console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

You cant use the calculator step, create a copy of field A, wich is the date that you want to change, and select the format date that you want, sorry for my english, is rusty, regards