# How to get the hour and minute of an UTC time

Tags: javascript

How can I see this time as  HH:MM:SS using javascript?

```
2019-07-25T09:35:38.193896+00:00
```

I've tried this code below but I got only my zone's time.

```js
var timeDate = new Date("2019-07-25T02:47:08.159794-07:00");
console.log(timeDate.toString());
var sa = timeDate.getHours();
var da = timeDate.getMinutes();
var san = timeDate.getSeconds();
console.log(sa);
console.log(da);
console.log(san);
```

I expect to see this time in HH:MM:SS format.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to show current time in JavaScript in the format HH:MM:SS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18229022/how-to-show-current-time-in-javascript-in-the-format-hhmmss)

Comment: @FedericoklezCulloca but when I do that I don't see the actual time I see my region's time.

Comment: @GuneyRal yeah, noticed that and removed my comment

Comment: I'm sure there's a duplicate somewhere, trying to find it.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Use JavaScript to convert a date string with timezone to a date object in local time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11770367/use-javascript-to-convert-a-date-string-with-timezone-to-a-date-object-in-local)

Comment: Just use `getUTCHours()` instead of `getHours()`.

Answer (score 3):

```
(new Date()).toUTCString().substring(17,25)
```

Output is

```
"09:58:59"
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 var d1 = new Date();
 d1.toUTCString();
 "Thu Jul 25 2019 15:15:06 GMT+0530"
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var timeDate = new Date("2019-07-25T09:35:38.193896+00:00");
console.log(`${timeDate.getUTCHours()}:${timeDate.getUTCMinutes()}:${timeDate.getUTCSeconds()}`);
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
function myFunction() {
  var d = new Date();
  var n = d.toLocaleTimeString();
  document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = n;
}
```

```html
<p id="demo"></p>
<button onclick="myFunction()">Try it</button>
```

Return the time portion of a Date object as a string, using locale conventions:

```
var d = new Date();
var n = d.toLocaleTimeString();
```

I found this on:
https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/tryit.asp?filename=tryjsref_tolocaletimestring

Answer (score 0):

There is two javascript fucntions for getting the Hours and Minutes:

Define a date like below:

```
var birthday = new Date('December 31, 1975, 23:15:30 GMT+11:00');
```

Use `getUTCHours` for getting hours:

```
console.log(birthday.getUTCHours());
// expected output: 23
```

Use `getUTCMinutes` for getting minutes:

```
console.log(birthday.getUTCMinutes());
// expected output: 15
```

See the mozilla documentation:

[JavaScript Demo: Date.getUTCHours()](https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Objets_globaux/Date/getUTCHours)

[JavaScript Demo: Date.getUTCMinutes()](https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Objets_globaux/Date/getUTCMinutes)

Comment: @Guney Ral, still have issues ? do not forget to accept the solution if is helpful so other people can profit from it as well.

Answer (score 0):

The toLocaleTimeString() method returns a string with a language sensitive representation of the time portion of this date. The new locales and options arguments let applications specify the language whose formatting conventions should be used and customize the behavior of the function. In older implementations, which ignore the locales and options arguments, the locale used and the form of the string returned are entirely implementation dependent. Read more here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/toLocaleTimeString

```js
function getTime() {
    let date = new Date();
    let time = date.toLocaleTimeString();
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = time;
}
```

```html
<p id="demo"></p>
<button onclick="getTime()">Check time</button>
```

You can also check it.

```
console.log(time.toLocaleTimeString('en-US'));
// expected output: 1:15:30 AM

console.log(time.toLocaleTimeString('it-IT'));
// expected output: 01:15:30

console.log(time.toLocaleTimeString('ar-EG'));
// expected output: ١٢:١٥:٣٠ ص
```